# JCheckBox tree cell renderer

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, tree, renderer

I've implemented a TreeCellRenderer that returns a JCheckBox (simple code that the renderer extends a JCheckBox and sets its selection status based on a flag in the item) and it works well. However, when there are more than a few items in the list, it renders VERY slowly. Scrolling in the list and expanding nodes takes over 1 second, which is quite slow. Is there a better way to implement a checkbox tree cell renderer to speed it up?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: There is maybe problem with your renderer. Make sure you are using only one instance of JCheckBox and not creating always new one for each request.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong. So post code if it is not too much trouble. Else expand on "simple code that the renderer extends a JCheckBox and sets its selection status based on a flag in the item" is that flag already given or is it computing the flag ? Also how many items in the list makes it slow?

Comment: I am only creating one checkbox, but I should be able to post code a little later today. I need to do some extra verification that it's not something else slowing down the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out there was something else in my app slowing things down.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use a third party library then you could use the CheckBoxTree from [JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm).